# Changing url when implementing pagination in asp.net using Grid View control

Tags: asp.net

I am creating blog for my website and I have used Grid View control to implement pagination but when I click on next button articles changes but Url does not change I want to change Url also when next articles are displayed. How Can i implement this if there is any link you can also paste that.

Comment: URl means ? Have you tried anything if so please provide some code snippets

Comment: Which URL ? What type of URL ? Explain in brief with some of code you have tried.

Comment: actually I am using Grid View control and enable it pagination porperty to true that puts numbers at the footer of Grid view control and when I click that number new e.g 5 posts are displayed on page and so forth but page url remains change I want to change page url also when next 5 posts should displayed if there is any alternative link plz provide me but remember I have to implement it in asp.net web application

Comment: @mudasir why do you want to change the URL while changing the Paging?

Comment: i need to refer people through link to a particular post

Comment: Sorry i am unable to understand your point ..need a screenshot or example what you need , unless a code i cant help you !!